# What is the right sequence in removing an application from ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

I know that for each applicatiThere are a few objects that need to be managed in ClearCase, VOB, View and projects. I'm still not clear what should be the sequence when I need to remove them, for example when a project is no longer valid and I want to remove everything about it.

Should it be:
1. Remove UCM baseline and project in Project Explorer
2. Remove View in Administrative Console
3. Remove VOB in Administrative Console
Any details I missed here?

I have go into a few situations so far, with orphan objects left in ClearCase, unable to remove them with warnings saying like "XXX tags missing......".

Answer (score 0):

You don't delete stuff in ClearCase.
Especially in ClearCase UCM, where an hard deletion can lead to some integrity issue for UCM objects (baselines or activities, with missing versions, composite baselines with missing dependencies, ...)

1. and 3. in particular are quite dangerous.

I would recommend simply "[`lock -obsolete`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm)" your projects and Streams (they will become invisible, and no-one will modify them again), and remove your view (2.)

You will find the same kind of solution in this technote "[Removing a UCM stream that has a delivered baseline](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146297)": potential integrity issue, and:

```
cleartool lock -obsolete stream:<stream>
```

---

Now, if you don't have that many interdependency, here is the sequence you would follow to remove an UCM project:

- remove all the views on all the Streams
- if you have done any activity, and or putting any baselines

  - remove all the baselines
  - remove all the versions (that is the part I don't like)
  - remove all the (now empty) activities
- remove the Streams
- remove the UCM Project

Comment: I see. Thanks for your reminder. But I still want to know if there's any particular sequence in removing an application. I guess this maybe useful when new applications are first added to ClearCase but somehow things goes wrong. It would be preferable to remove that particular application. You may consider that application is standalone, with no other applications linking to it.

Comment: @ArthasTsang: ok, I have edited my answer to address your comment. That details your 1/. I would never go with 3/ though (I would never remove a PVob)

Comment: @ArthasTsang: I agree, that is why I always `lock -obsolete` those old projects: quick and easy.